# Who's the Irish female J.A.R.V.I.S in Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, character-identification, avengers-age-of-ultron

I thought I knew a decent amount about Iron Man and The Avengers in general, but I've no idea who that Irish woman was in Iron Man's suit in Age of Ultron.

It really sticks in my mind because she had an especially stupid Irish accent. I'm Irish and it even annoyed me.

So in-universe, who is she and why did Tony Stark choose to give her an Irish accent?

Comment: You mean F.R.I.D.A.Y?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Avengers-Age-of-Ultron-2015-movie/Why-did-Starks-Friday-have-an-Irish-accent

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The alternate A.I. Tony uses after Jarvis was "unavailable" is F.R.I.D.A.Y. voiced by [Kerry Condon](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0174403/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t62)

This appears to be a reference to the Comic Book Earth 616 timeline. Instead of hiring a sectary Tony creates a "Girl Friday" A.I., who . . .

> when neglected, eventually turns against Tony

For more information on F.R.I.D.A.Y see this http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Friday_(Earth-616)

**Regarding Kerry Condons *stupid* Irish accent**

She's Irish, born and raised in Tipperary.
I actually recognised her voice as the Irish girl that turned up in an episode of the Walking Dead.

A strong regional accent like that can jar when heard out of context.

[image: Picture grabbed from Kerry Condons IMDB page]

Comment: This isn't really what the OP asked. This isn't an in-universe answer.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but don't really care about the actress at all. I know people from Tipp and her accent is over the top even for them... It actually sounds like an Irish person doing a bad Irish accent.

Comment: @Daft: Added information on F.R.I.D.A.Y., also dude, you obviously haven't been to the same parts of Tipp that I have.

Comment: In-Universe as far as the MCU goes, we don't have any information other than the name. While it would be awesome if this answered the question better, it's answered it as best as it can currently be answered.

Comment: @phantom42 not in the initial format but now its improved.